# Can I buy tickets to Neerpelt in Amsterdam (Schiphol), and where would I find that information?

Tags: trains, tickets, netherlands, belgium, amsterdam

I'm traveling to Neerpelt through Amsterdam (I will arrive at the Airport during a morning this weekend). Can I buy train tickets to Belgium, specifically Neerpelt, there?

Could I even pre-order them online, or is that not possible?

Comment: Most trains in Europe are mass transit. There is not really a need to buy tickets in advance.

Comment: @KristvanBesien for international tickets it is sometimes good to buy in advance. Last travel I needed a ticket from Antwerp, Belgium to Lille (Rijsel) France, could not buy it from the machines and had to wait quite a while and pay €5 extra in the ticket office. (I did buy more than just that one ticket, so not sure which of the tickets gave the extra cost.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the information and buy the tickets online [nl](https://www.nsinternational.nl/en/traintickets#/) [B](https://www.b-europe.com/EN), most likely you can buy part of your tickets, maybe all of them, also on the day at the station in the airport.

Buying on the day you can run into extra costs. There are tickets available to some places in Belgium and I can not check whether Neerpelt is one of them.

If you do not manage to get your tickets online and you can not get them all the way to Neerpelt, you can buy your ticket to the city in Belgium where you have to change trains and buy the rest from a ticket machine there.

Looking at Google Maps I see that combining train and buses (cross border) can be one hour faster than the train.
Within the Netherlands you can use [the 9292 site,](https://9292.nl/en) in Belgium ['De Lijn'](https://www.delijn.be/nl/) should be helpful.

In a comment the [Trainline](https://www.thetrainline.com/) is mentioned, I am not familiar with this version, but if it does buses as well, it might be great.

Comment: One more resource that I use more often now https://www.thetrainline.com/